# Receiving Exception 0xc0000005 after a new column addition to DataWindow

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm running into a very interesting issue that I've not been able to find a resolution for.  Stackoverflow has two 0xc0000005 PowerBuilder posts, but neither helped.

This is a Powerbuilder Classic 12.0/12.1 application.  The deployed application works fine as is.  But when I add a new column to this particular datawindow, say, FooColumn which is a CHAR(1) field.  Save the updated datawindow, deploy, and the application crashes at random locations (ascertained this via debugging) with an 0xc0000005 exception:

```
Faulting application name: PB120.EXE, version: 12.0.0.5530, time stamp: 0x4bb82661
Faulting module name: PBDWE120.dll, version: 12.1.0.7298, time stamp: 0x52280c40
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00095c6a
Faulting process id: 0x2908
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1d6f4d68ba638
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\PowerBuilder 12.0\PB120.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\PowerBuilder\PBDWE120.dll
Report Id: 260e4db8-4331-11e6-a0ba-0050568a1d6d
```

This occurs at very random locations in the code at different times (e.g. 1 minute after application runs, 5 minutes after application runs, etc).  Memory is not an issue.

Why is this happening?

The original source code works fine after re-deploying, then starts throwing exceptions and aborting without an exception trace (I added try/catch) when that new column was added to an existing data window (it's there, but never selected to be a part of the datawindow).

(As a side note: if I add new code without updating that particular datawindow, and deploy, the application runs happily to the end.)

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the datawindow object within the painter, i.e. from scratch.